# Convert a numpy float64 sparse matrix to a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have an `n x n` `numpy` `float64` `sparse matrix` (`data`, where `n = 44`), where the rows and columns are graph nodes and the values are edge weights:

```
>>> data
<44x44 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 668 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

>>> type(data)
<class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>

>>> print(data)
  (0, 7)    0.11793236293516568
  (0, 9)    0.10992000939300195
  (0, 21)   0.7422196678913772
  (0, 23)   0.0630039712667936
  (0, 24)   0.027037442463504143
  (0, 27)   0.16908845414214152
  (0, 28)   0.6109227233402952
  (0, 32)   0.0514765253537568
  (0, 33)   0.016341754080557713
  (1, 6)    0.015070325434709386
  (1, 10)   9.346673769086203e-05
  (1, 11)   0.2471018034781923
  (1, 14)   0.0020684269551621776
  (1, 18)   0.015258704502643251
  (1, 20)   0.021798149289490358
  (1, 22)   0.0087026831764125
  (1, 24)   0.1454235884185166
  (1, 25)   0.022060777594183015
  (1, 29)   0.9117391202819067
  (1, 30)   0.018557883854566116
  (1, 31)   0.001876070225734826
  (1, 32)   0.025841354399637764
  (1, 33)   0.014766488228364438
  (1, 39)   0.002791226433410351
  (1, 43)   1.0
  : :
  (41, 7)   0.8922099840113696
  (41, 10)  0.015776226631920767
  (41, 12)  1.0
  (41, 15)  0.1839408706622038
  (41, 18)  0.5151025641025642
  (41, 20)  0.4599130036630037
  (41, 22)  0.29378473237788827
  (41, 33)  0.47474890700697153
  (41, 39)  1.0
  (42, 2)   1.0
  (42, 10)  0.023305789342610222
  (42, 11)  0.011349136164776494
  (42, 12)  1.0
  (42, 17)  0.886081346522542
  (42, 18)  1.0
  (42, 30)  1.0
  (42, 40)  1.0
  (43, 1)   1.0
  (43, 6)   1.0
  (43, 11)  0.039948959300013256
  (43, 13)  1.0
  (43, 14)  0.02669811947637717
  (43, 29)  1.0
  (43, 30)  1.0
  (43, 36)  0.3381986531986532
```

I'd like to convert it to a `pandas` `data frame`, in order to write it to a file, with the columns: `node1, node2, edge_weight`, which will therefore give:

```
node1, node2, edge_weight
0, 7, 0.11793236293516568
0, 9, 0.10992000939300195
:, :, :
43, 36, 0.3381986531986532
```

Any idea how to do that?

Note that:

```
>>> pandas.DataFrame(data)
```

gives:

```
                                                    0
0     (0, 7)\t0.11793236293516568\n  (0, 9)\t0.109...
1     (0, 6)\t0.015070325434709386\n  (0, 10)\t9.3...
```

And

```
>>> pandas.DataFrame(print(data))
```

Gives:

```
  (0, 7)    0.11793236293516568
  (0, 9)    0.10992000939300195
```

So I guess `pandas.DataFrame(print(data))` is close to what I'm looking for.

Comment: What happens if you just call `pandas.DataFrame()`?

Comment: Just added an updated to my post regarding that

Comment: Can you share the array itself? Or a way to create some test data with the same shape? That output for `pandas.DataFrame(data)` is really bizarre...

Comment: `pandas.DataFrame(print(data))` prints your data and then creates an empty dataframe. I don't think this is a step in the right direction.

Comment: data is created by some package I'm using and unfortunately, I don't know how to create a test example of that.

Comment: can you try `type(data)` ?

Comment: Updated that to my post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This ipython session shows one way you could do it.  The two steps are: convert the sparse matrix to COO format, and then create the Pandas DataFrame using the `.row`, `.col` and `.data` attributes of the COO matrix.

```
In [50]: data                                                                                                    
Out[50]: 
<15x15 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 11 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

In [51]: print(data)                                                                                             
  (1, 12)   0.8581958095588134
  (6, 12)   0.03828052946099181
  (6, 14)   0.7908634838351427
  (7, 1)    0.7995008873930302
  (7, 11)   0.48477191537121145
  (7, 13)   0.6226526443518743
  (9, 4)    0.37242576669669103
  (11, 1)   0.9604278557580955
  (11, 5)   0.13285436036287313
  (12, 11)  0.5631419223609928
  (13, 8)   0.16481624650723847

In [52]: import pandas as pd                                                                                     

In [53]: c = data.tocoo()                                                                                        

In [54]: df = pd.DataFrame({node1: c.row, node2: c.col, edge_weight: c.data})                                   

In [55]: df                                                                                                      
Out[55]: 
    node1  node2  edge_weight
0       1     12     0.858196
1       6     12     0.038281
2       6     14     0.790863
3       7      1     0.799501
4       7     11     0.484772
5       7     13     0.622653
6       9      4     0.372426
7      11      1     0.960428
8      11      5     0.132854
9      12     11     0.563142
10     13      8     0.164816
```

Answer (score 13):

Can you try `toarray`

```
pd.DataFrame(A.toarray())
```

Comment: The problem with this is that if you have millions of nodes you will have millions of useless 0's if they even fit in memory. It's better to be able to simpy loop through non-zero values without literally creating millions of 0's. That is the whole idea of sparse matrices.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar problem when using `OneHotEncoder`
I fixed it by changing sparse to False

```
enc = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
```