# one hot encoder for the categorical variables of more one word

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I have a dataset like below. I want to do one hot encoding for logistic regression for the 'Item' column. There are 313 distinct items in the 'Item' column I'm getting below error. Can you please assist how to resolve it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uaYV.png)
Here is the code:

```
 from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
    from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
    ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('encoder', OneHotEncoder(), [0])], 
    remainder='passthrough')
    X = np.array(ct.fit_transform(X))**
```

array(<1126x316 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
with 4493 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>, dtype=object)

Comment: You can refer this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59339820/convert-a-numpy-float64-sparse-matrix-to-a-pandas-data-frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code, where `df` is the name of your dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.get_dummies(data = df, columns = ['Item'])
```

Comment: It shows this error: TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

Comment: @Aru Don't use NumPy array. Use this on pandas dataframe. I mean, load the dataset using pandas and apply this code, right away.